# Скрыть или показать выбранный елемент (сравнения) в select option

Tags: javascript

У меня есть таблица, в которой есть элементы. Первый по дефолту всегда виден. Изначально показываетсья только второй `td` (**No)** а потом по выбору user-а - если выбрал третий, соответсвенно третий(**size**) и так далее.

Но проблема в том, что я не могу добавить второй `tr` список. Его свойства не видны .То есть изначально при загрузке страницы видно первое свойство второго списка `tr`, но при выборе через `select option` он изчезает. Это связано с этой частью кода

```
i == divSelect ? elements[i].style.display = "block" : elements[i].style.display = "none";
```

Я не знаю каким образом  заменить счетчик, чтобы можно было добавить сколько угодно `tr` таблиц и сравнивать их таким образом друг под другом.

```js
function toggle_form_element (select) {
        let divSelect = select.value;
        let elements = document.querySelectorAll(".select-value");
        
        for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            i == divSelect ? elements[i].style.display = "block" : elements[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    };
```

```css
.mob-table .table thead tr {
  background-color: gray;
}
.mob-table .table thead tr th {
  text-align: center;
}
.mob-table .table thead tr th:first-child {
  text-align: left;
}
.mob-table .table tbody tr td {
  max-width: 130px;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.mob-table .table tbody tr td:nth-child(3) {
  display: none;
}
.mob-table .table tbody tr td:nth-child(4) {
  display: none;
}
.mob-table .table tbody tr td:nth-child(5) {
  display: none;
}
.mob-table .table tbody tr td:nth-child(6) {
  display: none;
}
.mob-table .table tbody tr td:nth-child(7) {
  display: none;
}
.mob-table .table tbody tr td:nth-child(8) {
  display: none;
}
.mob-table .table tbody tr td:first-child {
  text-align: left;
}
.mob-table .table tbody tr td .upload {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.mob-table .table tbody tr td .upload a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blue;
}
.mob-table .table tbody tr td .upload a button {
  background: none;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
.mob-table .table tbody tr td .room-img {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.mob-table .table tbody tr td a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
.mob-table .table tbody tr td .icon-person {
  padding-left: 10px;
  line-height: 2.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="mob-table">
      <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Rooms</th>
        <th scope="col">Compare  
          <select onchange="toggle_form_element(this);" name="parts" id="parts">
            <option value="0">No</option>
            <option value="1">Size</option>
            <option value="2">Occupancy</option>
            <option value="3">View</option>
            <option value="4">Beds</option>
            <option value="5">Bathrooms</option>

          </select>
        </th>

      </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <a href="javascript:void(0);">Standart Rooms <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            </td>
            <td class="align-middle select-value">XX</td>
            <td class="align-middle select-value">36 SQ M</td>
            <td class="align-middle select-value">2 <span class="icon-person"></span></td>
            <td class="align-middle select-value">Park, Interior</td>
            <td class="align-middle select-value"><span class="bed-icon-king"></span></td>
            <td class="align-middle select-value">Available on all floors</td>
            <td class="align-middle select-value">Full bathrooms</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>
              <a href="javascript:void(0);">Delux Rooms <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            </td>
            <td class="align-middle select-value">XX</td>
            <td class="align-middle select-value">36 SQ M</td>
            <td class="align-middle select-value">2 <span class="icon-person"></span></td>
            <td class="align-middle select-value">Park, Interior</td>
            <td class="align-middle select-value"><span class="bed-icon-king"></span></td>
            <td class="align-middle select-value">Available on all floors</td>
            <td class="align-middle select-value">Full bathrooms</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Может быть больше чем два `tr` списка они могут быть и 3 -5 даже 10 прошу это учитывать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При использовании функции `querySelectorAll(".select-value")` вы получаете массив в котором находятся все элементы с классом `select-value`, и таким образом у элементов из второго `tr` будут номера индексов после последнего элемента из первого `tr`

Попробуйте так, и нумерацию в select с 1

```js
function toggle_form_element (select) {
        let divSelect = select.value;
        let rows = document.querySelectorAll("tr");
        
        for (let i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
            let elements = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
            for (let j = 1; j < elements.length; j++) {
                j == divSelect ? elements[j].style.display = "block" : elements[j].style.display = "none";
            }
            
        }
};
```

```css
.mob-table .table thead tr {
  background-color: gray;
}
.mob-table .table thead tr th {
  text-align: center;
}
.mob-table .table thead tr th:first-child {
  text-align: left;
}
.mob-table .table tbody tr td {
  max-width: 130px;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.mob-table .table tbody tr td:nth-child(3) {
  display: none;
}
.mob-table .table tbody tr td:nth-child(4) {
  display: none;
}
.mob-table .table tbody tr td:nth-child(5) {
  display: none;
}
.mob-table .table tbody tr td:nth-child(6) {
  display: none;
}
.mob-table .table tbody tr td:nth-child(7) {
  display: none;
}
.mob-table .table tbody tr td:nth-child(8) {
  display: none;
}
.mob-table .table tbody tr td:first-child {
  text-align: left;
}
.mob-table .table tbody tr td .upload {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.mob-table .table tbody tr td .upload a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blue;
}
.mob-table .table tbody tr td .upload a button {
  background: none;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
.mob-table .table tbody tr td .room-img {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.mob-table .table tbody tr td a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
.mob-table .table tbody tr td .icon-person {
  padding-left: 10px;
  line-height: 2.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="mob-table">
      <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Rooms</th>
        <th scope="col">Compare  
          <select onchange="toggle_form_element(this);" name="parts" id="parts">
            <option value="1">No</option>
            <option value="2">Size</option>
            <option value="3">Occupancy</option>
            <option value="4">View</option>
            <option value="5">Beds</option>
            <option value="6">Bathrooms</option>

          </select>
        </th>

      </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <a href="javascript:void(0);">Standart Rooms <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            </td>
            <td class="align-middle select-value">XX</td>
            <td class="align-middle select-value">36 SQ M</td>
            <td class="align-middle select-value">2 <span class="icon-person"></span></td>
            <td class="align-middle select-value">Park, Interior</td>
            <td class="align-middle select-value"><span class="bed-icon-king"></span></td>
            <td class="align-middle select-value">Available on all floors</td>
            <td class="align-middle select-value">Full bathrooms</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>
              <a href="javascript:void(0);">Delux Rooms <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            </td>
            <td class="align-middle select-value">XX</td>
            <td class="align-middle select-value">36 SQ M</td>
            <td class="align-middle select-value">2 <span class="icon-person"></span></td>
            <td class="align-middle select-value">Park, Interior</td>
            <td class="align-middle select-value"><span class="bed-icon-king"></span></td>
            <td class="align-middle select-value">Available on all floors</td>
            <td class="align-middle select-value">Full bathrooms</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Наверное лучше даже `let rows = select.closest("table").querySelectorAll("tbody tr");`

Comment: спасибо большое.Вопрос а зачем нумерация с 1в селект ?из за того что и в цикле с 1 начинает?Баллы вознаграждения пока нельзя присвоить через 33 минуты.Принял ответ пока  с плюсиком и жду.

Comment: В 0 элементе массива будет `<a href="javascript:void(0);">Standart Rooms <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>`, а в селекте этой строки нет, поэтому с 1-го.